# How to use two variables as 1.hour method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I let users set default reminder settings.
They can set interval (integer) and period (string).

For example:

```
interval = 2
period = hours
```

I want to use these two variables to create a time period that I can add to a date.
Like the build in methods.

```
2.hours
```

I would like to use the above like so

```
interval.period
```

But if I do this I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `period' for 10:Integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the `send` method:

```rb
interval = 2
period = 'hours'

interval.send(period) # => 2 hours
```

Comment: You could use `public_send` instead of `send` which makes clear that you don't try to call a private method.

Comment: @FabianWinkler Can you explain maybe when to use `send` and when to use `public_send`? I know the difference between the 2, but I'm not sure when and why to use which.

Comment: You have to use send if you want to call a private method on an object. But this is considered as bad OOP practice. In my opinion public_send emphasises the point that you want to dynamically call a (public) method.